# Concurrent use of Judy Array

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, judy-array

I want a key value data structure which can support concurrent read operations by multiple threads in C support for 1M key values. I suppose Judy array is good both in terms of memory consumption & speed.

How does it stand in comparison to standard hash implementations by RCU or Google densehash?
Can I use single Judy array instance across Multiple threads?
in JUDYSL the value type is only uint can I store an instance of struct/object & how?

Answer (score 1):

The JudyArray implementation at code.google.com/p/judyarray supports multiple simultaneous readers in different threads.  Each thread needs to call judy_clone on the base judyarray to obtain its own array stack.

I don't know about the source forge version.

Comment: But that will increase the memory requirement & why it has to be cloned to be used by different thread? Not thread safe? Or does it perform any internal pointer updates to maintain states?

Comment: The entire array isn't cloned, just the path stack to the current judy element is created for use by another thread.